# Importing images from internet to new albums in iTunes

Tags: itunes, album-art

I just had an update for iTunes to version 12.0.1.26. The old way to import images to new albums in iTunes has changed. How do I import in the latest version?

Comment: Of interest: [Doug's AppleScripts for iTunes](http://www.dougscripts.com/itunes/index.php)

Answer (score 1):

1. Save your image cover -> Go to the album -> Right click on the empty cover -> Get Info -> Artwork -> click on add Artwork

[image]

2. Or simply right click on the empty cover -> Get album artwork